# Serial communication with python

Tags: python, serial-port

I'm fiddling a bit with python for serial communication, I have a switch that interacts with a screen and this screen in turn has 2 PCs connected to its HDMI ports, what I want to do is make this switch change from HDMI1 to HDMI2 port what I've been trying looks like this:

```py
import pyserial

connection = serial.Serial(
        'COM1',
        baudrate=9600,
        bytesize=8,
        patity='N',
        stopbits=1
    )
```

I really believe that the connection is well established, when I do the following `connection.is_open` the answer is True.

However, I think that my problem is in what is the correct way to compose the chain that sends the commands to the switch through the function `connection.write()`

- **r source!** ( Reading the input source at that time )
- **s source 1!** ( Switch HDMI1 input(1:HDMI1,2:HDMI2,
  3:HDMI3,4:DisplayPort,5:VGA/YPBPR/C-VIDEO) )
- **s hdmi1 auido 0!** ( Choice of audio source as audio input
  HDMI1 (0: Emb,1: Ext1,2: Ext2,3:Ext3,4:Ext4,5:Ext5) )

I really believe that my real problem is not knowing how to compose the command string that is sent with the function `write()` other aspect to consider is that I am using python 2.7 and windows.

the truth is that I am a newbie, if you can help me I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set a timeout and read until that happens

```
import pyserial
connection = serial.Serial(
        'COM1',
        baudrate=9600,
        bytesize=8,
        patity='N',
        stopbits=1,
        timeout=1 # could probably be less
    )
# maybe .... are there some docs for whatever switch you are using?
connection.write("r source!\n")
# you might need connection.write(b"r source!")
print(connection.read(1000)) # try and read 1000 bytes or until timeout ocurres(1 sec)
# if you knew what the terminal character the device sends is you could just readuntil that character
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, another interesting thing that the documentation says but the truth I can not fully understand excuse me for being such a rookie

Comment: **RS-232 controller**
VEO-SWM45 can be controlled by a third-party control system or it can
act as an RS232 step extension. For testing, software can be used
serial terminal (for example, Hercules, Putty ...). Connect the switch to a
PC / Mac with serial terminal software installed. Attention: The configuration of the
RS-232 port of the switch and software configuration (for example:
baud rate, data bits, parity, stop bits) must be the same.
After a chain of commands, the "Carriage Return" command is required
<CR> (0x0D).

Comment: This is the switch I am using but the truth does not say how to use it with python just mention Hercules, Puttyn for testing:

https://www.ecler.com/video/veo-swm45-detail.html

Comment: `connection.write("r source!\n")` you just need to end your command with `\n` (also from the docs it looks like the default `baudrate=115200`

Comment: Thanks again for answering, I will try it this way, because I am very novice I would like it if you know and I could recommend some documentation that can help me learn a little more about the serial ports and about things I can do with them and with Python in general to advance in IOT and do more interesting things

Comment: python is great for serial communication ... and this is really almost all there is to it